# How to host private NPM packages for free on GitHub based on a legacy private repo? Is it possible to do it without manual editions to package.json?

Tags: github, npm, publish, package.json, github-package-registry

My organization has a **private** repo on GitHub. Basically, a paid extension of [Sheetjs](https://sheetjs.com/) which works as a dependency for our web app project.

The task is to create a **private** NPM package for it. Hopefully, it would make the build process of the application easier.

The "most common way" to execute a task like this is via payment of US$ 7 per user, per month to host it directly at https://www.npmjs.com/

We are **not** following the path. Especially because we want this for just 1 repo. Instead, we *intend to host a private NPM package for free on GitHub.*

Hence, I am following [this tutorial from early-2020.](https://andreybleme.com/2020-05-31/hosting-private-npm-packages-for-free/)

My situation is a bit different from the author's. He assumes someone is creating a new package. I am wrapping something that already exists and works. What I did:

1 - Created a branch on our private repo

2 - Got my GitHub token locally

3 - I have a `.npmrc` file at `/Users/pedro` (using macOS) indicating:

```bash
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@my-organization-name:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=my-GitHub-token-which-will-not-be-shared-here-for-security-reasons
```

4 - Then, I **manually** changed the `package.json` file, inserting:

```js
"publishConfig": {
    "registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
}
```

5 - After this, I submitted the PR with the above-mentioned changes. The PR is waiting for a review.

If it gets merged, then I will do locally:

```bash
npm publish
```

My doubts are:

(i) - Did I miss something? Is this the correct approach as of mid-2022?

(ii) - Manual editions to package.json are [not recommended](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-book/issues/285). But, in this case, it seems mandatory. What would be the alternative?

(iii) If `npm publish` works, then the tutorial says:

> Any client properly authenticated into the Github Packages Registry
> can install the package by running:
>
> npm install @energicos/baseapp

Pragmatically speaking, what exactly does that mean?
Think about my co-workers that belong to the same GitHub organization and who already have access to the private repository, can they simply execute `npm install @my-organization/my-private-repo`?

If no, what exactly do they need to do to become a "*properly authenticated client on GitHub package registry*"?

(iv) - What would be the best way to test if the manual edition on `package.json` has broken something?

Obs.: This NPM/node world is new for me. Sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering:

(i) - Yes, this is the correct approach.

(ii) - To change the package name you need to do a manual edition. But, it is possible to use commands such as `npm ci` and `npm uninstall` when removing the old package and instaling the new one (obviously, after the package is already published)

(iii) - They do need a Personal Access Token and a `.npmrc` file including the right pointers

(iv) try a toy package and also use `npm link` before publishing stuff. See [this tutorial on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4b_T-qH3BY)